# there is an internal problem with your device

Tags: kernel

When I install my custom kernel i got this message after reboot.
The phone working normal no kernel panic or etc.

[system/build.prop](https://pastebin.com/raw/8mJqCJTp)

[vendor/build.prop](https://pastebin.com/raw/q0dQZgeV)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/LineageOS/android_vendor_lineage/commit/27180809c594cf6beeaeb206cced6fa42c086517 apparently that commit fixes it I have the same issue on a phone I made a kernel for, which I don't own.  Will know sometime tomorrow if it works.